# $5n+1$, $3n-1$ problem, smallest repeating cycle and Collatz conjecture

Tags: recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

Among the Collatz conjecture we have other "similar" problems that are solved and have repeating cycles.

$5n+1$ has the repeating cycle $13, 66, 33, 166, 83, 416, 208, 104, 52, 26$, with a length of $10$

[The $5n+1$ Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/the-5n1-problem)

$3n-1$ has the repeating cycle $5,14,7,20,10$

If there is a repeating cycle, must there its  smallest length be aprox. of size $2k$, where the algorithm is $kn\pm1$ for odd numbers?

Also, are the following diagrams meaningful?

[image: diagram 1]

[image: diagram 2]

First row of "Collatz" number diagram can be seen as N, second as 2N-1, third as 3N-1

If you look at diagram a), you can see that positional value y betwen 2x in forth row and x in third row is given by formula 4y-1

[image: diagram 3]

2 in column 1 => 4 in column 3

5 in column 3 => 10 in column 11

.
.
.

14 in column 5 => 28 in column 19

Another very naive, probably stupid but do not care subquestion? Finding some solution for $(3n-1)/2$ is the same as solving [system of equations with 2 unknowns](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2B1%3D3y%2B1%2C%202y%2B1%3D%283x%2B1%29%2F2).

Look at last diagram.  Can there be some generality written?

[image: diag4]

Comment: The $181n+1$ - problem has two cycles of much shorter length than $2 \cdot 181$ , namely something like $10$ or so. *(This was also known to R. Crandall 1978)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of structure which I think is not trivial. It is already mentioned in the [wikipedia-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), that cycles of *certain forms* could be disproved. (This might remind of the situation with the Fermat's last theorem in the time of Kummer, where finitely many prime exponents had already been excluded, and, I think to recall corrctly, by the Sophie Germain proof, also an infinite class of prime exponents).
The proofs of Ray Steiner[2,1977], and later [Simons/deWeger,2000 and 2002](http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) say, that there are no cycles of the form ***"uuuu....uuuddd...ddd"***, where *u* means upwards and *d* downward steps and all *d* 's are right of the *u* 's - and this is meant for any, thus unbounded, length. Then Simons proved, there are no cycles of the form ***"uuu...ddduuu...dddd"*** , which could be understood as concatenation of two of the first (now:) partial cycles.

To give it a name, they called the the first one the *"1-cycle"* and the concatenations as *"m-cycles"* where Simons/deWeger could proceed to the disproof of *m-cycles* of up to *m=68*.

---

A very general tool for the discussion of cycles (and the possible disproof for certain finite lengthes) follows from the following observation:

define the one step-transformation for some $w n + 1$ - problem in the following shorter form
$$ b = {(w a + 1 ) \over 2^A}  $$
over the odd numbers *a* and *b*, where the exponent $A$ is uniquely chosen to make *b* an odd integer. Then consider the sequence of steps
$$ b = {(w a + 1 ) \over 2^A}  \qquad
   c = {(w b + 1 ) \over 2^B}  \qquad
   d = {(w c + 1 ) \over 2^C}  \qquad
   e = {(w d + 1 ) \over 2^D}  \qquad
$$
where we have a cycle, if we finally have $a = e$
Obviously the product of the numbers *a,b,c,d* must equal the product of its transforms, so we ask whether -with asome *a,b,c,d*, we can find equality
$$ bcda \overset{?}{=} ({w a + 1  \over 2^A})({w b + 1  \over 2^B})({w c + 1  \over 2^C})({w d + 1  \over 2^D})$$ 
(whose generalization to as many steps as wished is obvious). Then rearranging and cancelling gives
$$ 2^{A+B+C+D} \overset{?}{=} (w+ \frac 1a)(w+ \frac 1b)(w+ \frac 1c)(w+ \frac 1d) \tag {1} $$ and writing *S* for the sum of exponents and *N* for the number of steps we can rewrite the question of existence of the cycle whether we can have equality
$$ 2^S \overset{?}{=} w^N (1+ \frac 1{wa})(1+ \frac 1{wb})(1+ \frac 1{wc})(1+ \frac 1{wd}) \tag 2 $$ from where then
$$ w^N \lt 2^S \overset{?}{=} w^N(1+z) $$
where *z* is small, and decreases when *a,b,c,d* increase. This imposes the general problem of distance of perfect powers; for the example case *w=3* we can disprove for instance the 4-step-cycle:
We assume *a,b,c,d* the smallest and different odd values *a=5,b=7,c=11,d=13* . We get
 $$ 2^S \overset{?}{=}  (3+ \frac 15)(3+ \frac 17)(3+ \frac 1{11})(3+ \frac 1{13}) \\
    2^S \overset{?}{=} 81 + 27( \frac 15 + \frac 17+\frac 1{11}+\frac 1{13}) + 9( \cdots) + 3(\cdots) + {1 \over 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13} $$
and we see, that the rhs can never be as large as the next perfect power of 2 above $3^4$ because we must then have $2^S = 128$ and actually
$$  \begin{eqnarray}  2^S &=&128 & \gt && 81 + 27( \frac 15 + \frac 17+\frac 1{11}+\frac 1{13}) + \varepsilon\\
 & & & & \sim & 81 + 14.64... \end{eqnarray}$$
even if we *increase* the assumed values for *a,b,c,d* up to some *trillion* and try whether we can find a solution for the 4-step-cycle there...

In the same way this can be done for more steps, and for many number-of-steps this simple tool suffices for the disproof of the existence of a cycle.

Similarly this can be done for other instances of *w*; and especially if the numbers *a,b,c,d,...* are in a certain progression (like it is with the structure of the 1-cycle) we can find/identify, or prove the nonexistence of cycles. In the $3n+1$ the 1-cycle defines the progression in $a_1,a_1,a_2,...,a_N$ as  $a_{k+1} = a_k + (a_k+1)/2 $ and this suffices for the Steiner-proof (which uses results from the rational approximation of linear forms of logarithms).

Also, if we consider the $w n - 1$ - case, in (2) we simply replace the plus by the minus-sign. Note, then we find then for the $3 n - 1$-problem the cycles of the collatz-transform in the negative integers because then formula (1) and (2) for one,two and six steps give the respective solutions.

---

But it is as mentioned above: this reminds me a bit of the FLT-problem in the early 20'th century, when isolated prime-exponents could be excluded, and even infinite subclasses, but not yet the whole set of possible primes.

[2] Steiner, R.P.; "A theorem on the syracuse problem", Proceedings of the 7th Manitoba Conference on Numerical Mathematics, pages 553–559, 1977

Comment: @Helms Do you know that, if you disprove $10^{100}$ cycle doesn't exist,  This is not prove the $10^{1000}$ cycle doesn't exist.And I do not think your method will get us anything.

Answer (score 5):

If you take $k=2^m-1$, then the $kn+1$ problem maps $$1 \mapsto 2^m \mapsto 2^{m-1} \mapsto \cdots \mapsto 1.$$  In this case, the cycle length is $O(\log k)$.  This is significantly different to $2k$.  (A similar construction works for the $kn-1$ problem.)

Answer (score 4):

Nobody knows much of anything about the length of cycles for Collatz-type problems. After all, for all we know, the $3n+1$ problem could have a cycle of length $10^{100}$.

Comment: Are there *any* known nontrivial solutions to Collatz-type problems?

Comment: @Aaron, to the best of my knowledge, there is no non-trivial Collatz-type problem that has been completely solved.

Comment: @Myserson Do you think of the existence of counterexample?

Comment: @Mat, you mean an example of $k$ with a cycle of length exceeding $2k$ for the $kn\pm1$ problem? I have no opinion on the existence of such $k$.

Comment: @myserson No..I mean only $"3n + 1"$ problem.

Comment: @Mat, please do me the courtesy of spelling my name correctly. I have no opinion as to the situation with regard to the $3n+1$ problem.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry @Gerry Myerson It happened without knowing..sorry again. You say in your answer cycle lenth for $"3n+1"$ ? may be $10^{100}$..??

Comment: Well, yes, for all we know, there could be a cycle of length $10^{100}$. But I don't have an opinion one way or the other on whether there is such a cycle. I haven't studied the problem deeply enough to form any opinions on it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  hmm..I understood..your answer for me +1) because I am thinking like you...