# Is it possible to find $ψ(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples, collatz-conjecture

Inspired by the question 
[Is $\lim_{k \to \infty}\left[ \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{M}{1+3+5+7+\cdots+ [2^{p(k-1)}-2^{p(k-2)}-2^{p(k-3)}-\cdots-1]}\right]=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414343/) which that, I asked before.
I researched the pdf books before asking this question at MSE. When I could not find an answer anywhere, I decided to ask. Even if the question is absurd.

For this function:
$$f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\text{if } n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}\\ n+1 & \text{if } n\equiv 1 \pmod 2. \end{cases}$$

We know that for any positive number, there is such a number $\text{“} k \text{''}$, which that $f^k(n)=1$

For function $f(n)$ go "backward" from number $1$ for **only odd numbers sequence:**

Let step number is $k$
 $$[2^{\sum_{z=1}^k m_z}-2^{\sum_{z=2}^k m_z}-2^{\sum_{z=3}^k m_z}-\cdots-1]\stackrel{k\to \infty}{\longleftarrow}\mathbf{\cdots} \stackrel{k=5}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[2^{m_4+m_3+m_2+m_1}-2^{m_4+m_3+m_2}-2^{m_4+m_3}-2^{m_4}-1]}\stackrel{k=4}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[{2^{m_1+m_3+m_2}-2^{m_2+m_3}-2^{m_3}-1}]}\stackrel{k=3}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[{2^{m_1+m_2}-2^{m_2}-1}]}\stackrel{k=2}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[{2^{m_1}-1}]}\stackrel{k=1}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf1$$

I used this formula:

$$φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k})=φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k-1}})×2^{m_k}-1$$

and  we can find general distrubition function: $φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k})$

$$φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k}})=[2^{\sum_{z=1}^k m_z}-2^{\sum_{z=2}^k m_z} - 2^{\sum_{z=3}^k m_z}-\ldots-1]$$

$$f^k(φ(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k))=f^k([2^{\sum_{z=1}^k m_z}-2^{\sum_{z=2}^k m_z} - 2^{\sum_{z=3}^k m_z}-\cdots-1])=1$$

Example:

$$f^2(φ(m_1,m_2))=f^2({2^{m_1+m_2}-2^{m_2}-1})=\frac{\frac{{2^{m_1+m_2}-2^{m_2}-1} + 1}{2^{m_2}}+1}{2^{m_1}}=1$$

Then, look at this function:

$$g(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\text{if } n \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\ 3n+1 & \text{if } n \equiv 1 \pmod 2. \end{cases}$$

For function $g(n)$ go "backward" from number $1$ for **only odd numbers sequence**, again:

$$ψ(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k)\stackrel{k\to \infty}{\longleftarrow}\mathbf{\cdots} \stackrel{k=2}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[\frac{4^{m_1}-1}{3}]}\stackrel{k=1}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf1$$

$$ψ(m_1)=\frac{4^{m_1}-1}{3}$$

Because, $g^1(ψ(m_1))=1$

The problem starts here. I found $ψ(m_1)$ for $k=1$. But, I dont know, how can I find $ψ(m_1,m_2)$ or $ψ(m_1,m_2,m_3)$.I can not continue here.

Anyway.My question's "meat" is this: 
Is it possible to make a general formula by going back from $1$?

> How can we find and **is it possible** $ψ(m_1,m_2),ψ(m_1,m_2,m_3)...ψ(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k)$?
>
> If we find, general dispersion $ψ(m_1,m_2),ψ(m_1,m_2,m_3),...,ψ(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k)$ can we answer that question: Why, is there such a number $k$ for function $f(n)$ always $f^k(n)=1$ and $g^k(n)=1$ or $g^k(n)≠1$(counterexample)?

*The question is open to any editing, because I know, there are flaws in question and formulas.*

Comment: The iterates of the Collatz function $g(2n) = n, g(2n-1) = 3(2n-1)+1$ cannot be put in a strictly decreasing form.

Whereas the iterates of $f(2n) = n, f(2n-1) = 2n$ can be put in the form $F(2n)=n,F(2n-1) = n$. $ \qquad \qquad$ $ \qquad \qquad$ $ \qquad \qquad$ Formulas with $\ldots$ are hard to read. Your function $f(n)$ can be replaced by $F(2n-1) = 2n, F(2^k (2n-1)) = 2n-1$ whose iterations go to $1$. The backward sequence is of the form $a_1 = 1, a_{i+1} = 2^{k_i} a_i -1$ so that $a_i = F(a_{i+1})$. Then say $\varphi((k_i)_{i=1}^j )=  a_j$.

Comment: @reuns ohh, maybe I asked wrong. I look only odd numbers

Comment: What do you mean ? And the same idea of backward sequence works for any iterated function with $f^{-1}$ being two-valued  (here $f^{-1}(2n+1) \in \{2 (2n+1),2n\}$)

Comment: @ruins question was fixed.

Comment: Since $n_{k-1}$ is odd,you can write it mod 9(=1,2,4,5,7,8). Sorry can't comment yet

Answer (score 3):

For $k=3$ it seems a bit more complicated. The third exponent must be something like $2o + (l-n)mod$ 3. I'll try to find out later.

I think this needs a more systematic way.

let's say $n_{(k-1)}=\frac{3n_k+1}{2^{m_k}}$, with $n_0=1$.
If you want to climb up the tree, you can't pass through multiple of 3 (the $n_{(k-1)}$ cannot be multiple of 3, this is well known and obvious when you replace in the above formula). Here are the valid $m_k$ for different $n_{(k-1)}$ to avoid multiple of 3:

$n_{(k-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod {18}$ => $m_k$ must be of the form $6x+2$ or $6x+4$

$n_{(k-1)}\equiv 11 \pmod {18}$ => $m_k$ must be of the form $6x+1$ or $6x+3$

$n_{(k-1)}\equiv 13 \pmod {18}$ => $m_k$ must be of the form $6x+2$ or $6x+6$

$n_{(k-1)}\equiv 5 \pmod {18}$ => $m_k$ must be of the form $6x+3$ or $6x+5$

$n_{(k-1)}\equiv 7 \pmod {18}$ => $m_k$ must be of the form $6x+4$ or $6x+6$

$n_{(k-1)}\equiv 17 \pmod {18}$ => $m_k$ must be of the form $6x+1$ or $6x+5$

Perhaps if we use the general formula with the desired $k$ level: 
$\frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_3+m_2+m_1)}}{3^k} - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_3+m_2)}}{3^k} - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_3)}}{3^{k-1}} - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_4)}}{3^{k-2}} -  ....  -  .... - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1})}}{3^3} - \frac{2^{(m_k)}}{3^2} - \frac{2^0}{3^1}$

and by replacing the $m_k$ by valid forms ($6x+y$ from the modulo list above), like i did in the previous answer, we must be able to construct the formulas.

Note: for the highest $m_k$ you don't need to avoid multiple of 3 (they are valid values), so you can use the $2l$ or $2l+1$ forms instead, like i did in the previous answer too.

I have not much time now, i'll take a look later, but i still think that having a unique formula or working with the $m_k$ alone is almost impossible.

EDIT:
Ok, one of the formulas for $k=3$ is

$\frac{2^{m_3+m_2+m_1}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_3+m_2}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_3}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3^1}$ with $m_1=18n+2$, $m_2=18l+2$ and $m_3=2o$ which gives

$\frac{16\cdot4^o\cdot262144^{n+l}-4\cdot4^o\cdot262144^l-3\cdot4^o-9}{27}$

I used $18x+2$ instead of $6x+2$ because the patern repeats every 3 times (e.g. the multiple of 3 is in first position for exponent $6\cdot3\cdot x+2$)

So i think you can split to avoid using modulos like i thought. Anyway, this gives a lot of possible formulas to cover $k=3$, and even more for $k=4$... which is not practicable...unless we can find some sort of systematic way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

$φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k}})=\frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_3+m_2+m_1)}}{3^k} - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_3+m_2)}}{3^k} - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_3)}}{3^{k-1}} - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1}+...+m_4)}}{3^{k-2}} -  ....  -  .... - \frac{2^{(m_k+m_{k-1})}}{3^3} - \frac{2^{(m_k)}}{3^2} - \frac{2^0}{3^1}$

If you apply successively the condensed formula $g'(n)=\frac{3n+1}{2^{m_i}}$ to it, you'll reach 1.

k being the "distance" to 1, answering to "why is there such a number k" is answering the conjecture.

EDIT:
I used your layout so you can understand better:

For function $g(n)$ go "backward" from number $1$ for **only odd numbers sequence:**

**Note: This is how the Collatz tree is contructed**

Let step number is $k$
 $$[\frac{2^{\sum_{z=1}^k m_z}}{3^k}-\frac{2^{\sum_{z=2}^k m_z}}{3^k}-\frac{2^{\sum_{z=3}^k m_z}}{3^{k-1}}-\cdots-\frac{1}{3}]\stackrel{k\to \infty}{\longleftarrow}\mathbf{\cdots} \stackrel{k=5}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[\frac{2^{m_4+m_3+m_2+m_1}}{3^4}-\frac{2^{m_4+m_3+m_2}}{3^4}-\frac{2^{m_4+m_3}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_4}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3}]}\stackrel{k=4}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[{\frac{2^{m_3+m_2+m_1}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_3+m_2}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_3}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3^1}}]}\stackrel{k=3}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[{\frac{2^{m_2+m_1}}{3^2}-\frac{2^{m_2}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3}}]}\stackrel{k=2}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{[{\frac{2^{m_1}}{3^1}-\frac{1}{3^1}}]}\stackrel{k=1}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf1$$

I used this formula:

$$φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k})=φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k-1}})×\frac{2^{m_k}-1}{3}$$
**(which is the inverse of the Collatz function $\frac{3n+1}{2^{m_k}}$ since we run backward)**

and  we can find general distrubition function: $φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k})$

$$φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k}})=[\frac{2^{\sum_{z=1}^k m_z}}{3^k}-\frac{2^{\sum_{z=2}^k m_z}}{3^k} -\frac{2^{\sum_{z=3}^k m_z}}{3^{k-1}}-\ldots-\frac{1}{3}]$$

$$g^k(φ(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k))=g^k([\frac{2^{\sum_{z=1}^k m_z}}{3^k}-\frac{2^{\sum_{z=2}^k m_z}}{3^k} -\frac{2^{\sum_{z=3}^k m_z}}{3^{k-1}}-\ldots-\frac{1}{3}])=1$$

Example:

$$g^2(φ(m_1,m_2))=g^2(\frac{2^{m_1+m_2}}{3^2}-\frac{2^{m_2}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3})=\frac{3(\frac{3(\frac{2^{m_1+m_2}}{3^2}-\frac{2^{m_2}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3})+1}{2^{m_2}})+1}{2^{m_1}}=1$$

Note that $ψ(m_1)=\frac{4^{m_1}-1}{3}$ is correct, but above, it was written as $\frac{2^{m_1}-1}{3}$ because  other exponents $m_x$ are not always even.

Also note that my answer [k being the "distance" to 1, answering to "why is there such a number k" is answering the conjecture] refers to the previously unedited question: "Why,is there such a number $k$ for function $g(n)$ always $g^k(n)=1$" which is the conjecture itself and nobody can answer yet: when you run backward, you have to prove that you reach all naturals from 1.

EDIT2:
The $m_k$ are totally dependent of the parent value $φ$, so there is no way to have a unique formula (with $m_k$ being any natural). For $k=2$ you could write these two formulas (they give all naturals that are 2 steps from 1): one with $m_1=6n+4$ and $m_2=2l+1$: $\frac{32\cdot64^n\cdot4^l-2\cdot4^l-3}{3^2}$ and one with $m_1=6n+2$ and $m_2=2l$(preferably with l>0, but i think it works with 0): $\frac{4\cdot64^n\cdot4^l-4^l-3}{3^2}$, but it does not help much (with $k=3$ you multiply the number of formulas...). You can have an infinite succession of $m_k=1$ (e.g. for $2^y-1$ there is $y-1$ successives $m_k=1$, so you can't predict $m_{k+1}$ with other $m_k$'s), or other combinations, but they are dependent of the successive values they produce (you can't just replace $m_4=1$ by $m_4=2$ or $3$, it would completly change the possible values of $m_{5+}$. If it was so simple, Collatz would be proved by now.

Comment: Ohh, sorry I did not do downvote, but I do not understand you.

Comment: İn your solution we dont know what is ${m_2,m_3...}$

Comment: $m_1$ is always even: $0, 2, 4,...$. $m_2$ is dépendent of $m_1$, and any $m_k$ is dépendent of the previous $m_k$'s (more precisely of the previous φ) . In $φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k})=φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k-1}})×\frac{2^{m_k}-1}{3}$, the rule is: if $φ({m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{k-1}})$ is of the form $6x+1$, $m_k$ is even (including 0), if it is of the form $6x+5$, $m_k$ is odd. E.g. 11 = 6x1+5 -> $m_k$ can be $1, 3, 5, ...$. If you take $m_k=1$, you'll end up on 7.

Comment: Please, write for $k=2$ direct formula.

Comment: what do you mean? this one: $\frac{2^{m_2+m_1}}{3^2}-\frac{2^{m_2}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3}$? there is no shortcut: if $m_1=4$   ($φ=5$), then $m_2$ can be $1, 3, 5, 7,...$ to give the next φ ($3, 13, 53, ...$). if $m_1=8$   ($φ=85$), then $m_2$ can be $2, 4, 8,...$ to give the next φ ($113, 453,  ...$). (sorry i said 0 included for even, but it is 0 excluded)

Comment: I want to say ,write for example: $m_1=2n$, or $m_1=2n+1$ finally, general formula for $k=2$

Comment: $\frac{32×64^n×4^l-2×4^l-3}{9}$ is not natural number.  Try $l=2,n=3$

Comment: I find 14913077

Comment: Compute '{1/9 (4×64^n×4^l - 2×4^l - 3), n = 3, l = 2}' with the Wolfram|Alpha website (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B1%2F9+%284%C3%9764%5En%C3%974%5El+-+2%C3%974%5El+-+3%29%2C+n+%3D+3%2C+l+%3D+2%7D) or mobile app (wolframalpha:///?i=%7B1%2F9+%284%C3%9764%5En%C3%974%5El+-+2%C3%974%5El+-+3%29%2C+n+%3D+3%2C+l+%3D+2%7D).

Comment: The other formula is this one $\frac{4\cdot64^n\cdot4^l-4^l-3}{3^2}$. You added a mult 2 in it.

Comment: by your method can you write, $k=3$ or $k=4$ at least?, **ıs it possible**

Comment: I think this is possible, at least for $k=3$. I'll check this tonight. This is not straightforward since the $m_k$ depend of the values and not directly of the other $m_k$'s. The idea is to do the same as above with $\frac{2^{m_3+m_2+m_1}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_3+m_2}}{3^3}-\frac{2^{m_3}}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3^1}$, but there are some twists.